# Global reactive state with Vue.js Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-composition-api

What is the best solution for use vue-composition API like vuex?

```js
import { reactive, readonly } from "vue";

const state = reactive({
  count: 0
});

const increment = function () {
  state.count++;
}

export default { state: readonly(state), increment };
```

Comment: There is no 'best' way. It depends on what Vuex features you need to implement. Do you have problems with the code you posted?

Comment: No, I don't have any problems this OK! but I want better way like class or use TypeScript.. what's users suggest!?

Comment: Making it TS-friendly is a different task. Classes aren't really useful here, can be achieved with plain objects. For types it makes sense to define state as a part of store object and infer `state` type from `this` in actions and getters, otherwise you'll have to provide explicit types. You can create helper function that will do additional work for store definition, i.e. `bind` for actions and `reactive` for state. Check how Pinia defines stores, this way it works ok for TS.